# Can i post feeds to all my app users via loop in facebook?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

```
    $data2 = array();
    $data2['access_token'] = $usersPermission; // from database

    $data2['message'] = 'test message';

    $facebook->api('/'.$facebook_user_id.'/feed/', 'post', $data2)
```

i have above code in a loop. this loop will post feed to 10000s of my users wall. Is there any problem if i do like this? i mean is there any chance it consider as a spam? can do this without loop?

Comment: :O why would you want to do that? It would be spam imo, nothing says spam more than 1000s of posts of the same thing within seconds. Facebook has changed its graph api lately I'm not entirely sure you can post to friends feeds anymore.

Comment: Why not just put the message on your apps own page?

Comment: i have two type user (a and b) for same app. i wand to post some data only to user a, and athor data only to user b

Answer (score 0):

**DON'T** Ever try to send the same post to all users at the same time , your application will be **banned** .

try to make a good publish algorithm to send your posts and consider the time delay between each post.

you can split your users into groups **ex.** you can publish for 25 user every 5 minutes.